# Display “tooltip” Help bubble on widgets like TextField in Vaadin

Tags: hover, tooltip, vaadin, help-system

I want to display a floating bubble with online-help info when the user hovers the mouse pointer, like a tooltip seen on a button-tool-bar in other apps.

I know that we can pass an initial value when setting up a widget such as `TextField`. And I see [on this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7010239/642706) that we can provide an initial prompt to the user, a placeholder until the user enters a value into that field. But I want to provide Help assistance whether or not the user has entered a value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `Description` property

### Vaadin 7

Call the getter/setter methods for a property on most widgets called *Description*: [`getDescription`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/7.7/7.7.13/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent.html#getDescription--) and [`setDescription`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/7.7/7.7.13/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent.html#setDescription-java.lang.String-)

### Vaadin 8

Call the getter/setter methods for a property on most widgets called *Description*: [`getDescription`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.4/8.4.5/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent.html#getDescription--) and [`setDescription`](https://vaadin.com/download/release/8.4/8.4.5/docs/api/com/vaadin/ui/AbstractComponent.html#setDescription-java.lang.String-)

See the [*Sampler* page for `TextField`](https://demo.vaadin.com/sampler/#ui/data-input/text-input/text-field). The *Description* property is empty initially there. Click the gear icon, and enter text in the `Description` field and press Enter/Return. For example:

[image]

### Vaadin 10 (Vaadin Flow)

Vaadin Flow as of 10.0.1 lacks the hovering help feature. Such a feature is [being considered](https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/4169).

Comment: Your observation is right, the feature is not implemented yet. We have feature request ticket in GitHub for that here: https://github.com/vaadin/flow/issues/4169